# How many rows have been added or updated across all tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are considering [SymmetricDS](http://www.jumpmind.com/buy-now?product=symmetricds) Pro to handle database replication on our SQL Server 2016 database. However, they license their product based on number of rows across all tables that are inserted or updated per day.

We have a large multi-tenant database, with many tables, and we really don't have a grasp on this number.  I've been on Google trying to figure out how to measure this, or how to figure it out, and I'm struggling.

I did find [this tutorial](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/reading-sql-server-change-tracking-results/) which describes how to use CHANGETABLE, but so far I'm not seeing a way to use this across all tables, and I am hoping to avoid doing a query for every table (as there are a lot of them).  And, I am a lot less concerned about row versions and much more concerned about real-world dates.  (How many rows were added or changed on 8/26, for example.)

Is it possible to discover this historically via a query?  Or is this something we will need to measure real time? (I want to avoid the later, for performance reasons.)

Comment: Have you looked at Temporal Tables? They're not for this purpose but I can see how you might use them. SQL Server doesn't inherently track any information about row modifications unless you go log diving frequently or use a technology that does it for you (change tracking, change data capture, etc). Or the heavier things like trace / extended events / auditing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, "Have you looked at Temporal Tables?".... Nope, but I'm about to!

Answer (score 1):

Casey, full disclosure I work at JumpMind and specifically on the SymmetricDS team.  The license restriction around rows only prevents use of the web console.  Replication would remain intact and functioning.  If you want to download a trial or contact sales we can work with you on determining your usage.

Comment: thanks Josh!  We are still looking at all options. But this is great to know!